# Geometrical Interpretation with vectors

Tags: vectors

Question: Two vectors $u$ and $v$ are at 90° to each other oriented tail to tail. If both vectors have magnitude 1, then:

a) $u + v = 2$

b) $|u| + |v| = 2$

c) $|u - v| = \sqrt{2}$

d) $u - v = 0$

*I'm very confused on which option is correct. I believe a) or d) can't be it because the absolute value must be included because of the magnitude. However, I don't understand which answer is correct. b) or c). If someone can help me out, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Draw the picture of the vectors $u$, $v$ and $u-v$. Note that $u-v + v = u$ and it should be obvious to you.

Comment: Use the well known vectors in the plane $\;(1,0),\,(0,1)\;$ as example. Check that, for example, (a) and (d) cannot be with their help. Try to think which of (b)-(c) is true (and it is pretty easy after you get used to this stuff), and then try to prove it in general.

Comment: perhaps b) and c) are both correct

Comment: @J.W.Tanner unfortunately there can only be one correct answer

Comment: @DonAntonio b) and c) are correct or I misunderstood the question: $$\lvert u\rvert+\lvert v\rvert=1+1=2,\quad \lvert u-v\rvert=\sqrt{\langle u-v,u-v\rangle}=\sqrt{\lvert u\rvert^2-2\langle u,v\rangle+\lvert v\rvert^2}=\sqrt{1-0+1}=\sqrt 2.$$

Comment: If b) were $|u+v|=2,$ then b) would be incorrect

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Yes, they are both correct: "or" in mathematics is always inclusive, unless otherwise explicitly stated.